# Is there any way to protect NPCs from Emissary of Barachiel?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

One of my friends keeps complaining that a guy in his game, who is playing an Emissary Of Barachiel, is breaking the game by converting every NPC that was supposed to betray the group to the lawful good side.

Now one of my players is thinking of going for the same prestige class and I don't want to end up in a similar situation. Is there a way to prevent Emissary Of Barachiel from switching someone's alignment, whether by NPCs possessing certain feats or some sort of demonic protection I can give to key NPCs?

Specifically I'm looking for protections against **Calling (Su)** and **Conversion (Su)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, beware of *Book of Exalted Deeds*, it can be quite broken (*Saint*, in particular), especially if the role-play requirements are not enforced.

With that being said, the *Calling (Su)* and *Conversion (Su)* class features of the *Emissary of Barachiel* are simply impossible to save against, seeing as they pit a *Diplomacy* check versus a *Will* save: it is just much easier to boost a skill check than it is to boost a save.

On the other hand:

> An *Emissary* can use this ability once per day per class level, spending a full-round action to issue the call.
>
> *Humanoid* creatures within 30 feet of the *Emissary* are potentially affected.
>
> *Calling* is an *Enchantment (Compulsion) [Language-Dependent, Mind-Affecting]* effect.

And thus given the wording of the *Conversion (Su)* ability, I will assume that it is too.

This has several implications:

- A Full-Round action occupies a whole turn, which generally precludes any other Move/Standard action.
- The range is short, any creature further away (archers, casters) is unaffected.
- Only *Humanoid* are affected, thereby a strict reading could exclude *Monstrous Humanoid* which can make the bulk of your foes. *Giant*, *Fey* and *Undead* are also a category of their own, and there are LA +0 templates to turn into *Fey* or *Undead*.
- The effect is powerless unless the foe understands the *Emissary*. That is, unless the *Emissary* speaks the foe's language OR uses a spell to be understood, the ability has no effect.
- The effect is likely powerless unless the foe hears the *Emissary*, a deaf foe, or a foe in a zone of *Silence*, cannot hear the *Emissary*. For example, casting Silence on a pebble and slipping it into the *Emissary*'s pocket undetected...
- The effect is powerless against creatures immune to *Enchantment* or *Mind-Affecting* effects (though I am not sure if any *Humanoid* race is immune).
- *Conversion (Su)* is acquired at ECL 8 at the soonest, by then intelligent foes should have some generic counters for *Enchantment* or *Mind-Affecting* effects as those are nasty effects you really don't want to succumb to. Check the [List of Necessary Magic Items](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items) to equip your NPCs, in this case: the 1st-level spell [Protection From Good](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromEvil.htm) suppresses the effects of *Enchantment (Compulsion)* for its duration (1 min/lvl).

All in all, using *Calling (Su)* or *Conversion (Su)* seems like a good way to waste a full-round action in the middle of combat.

Also, out of combat, someone who gains a reputation for bullying others into helping him may easily be barred from the nobles mansions/king's court/etc... Coercion has social consequences, see the rules on the use of *Intimidate*.

Comment: Second last bullet: examples are poorly chosen, because these creatures are already immune due to not being humanoids.

Comment: @Mołot: Good point, edited them out. I cannot think of any humanoid race who is fully immune. Elves get a bonus, but +4 is not that helpful versus a Diplomacy skill check.

Comment: You have confused a full-round action with a 1-round action. Totally understandable mistake to make, but numerous claims about disrupting things it moving away are incorrect. A full-round action takes your whole turn but completes on your turn.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu Since you already accepted this answer as-is, I wanted to draw your attention to my comment here. There is a fairly major error in it.

Comment: @KRyan: Oh, that's embarrassing :(

Comment: See also: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119558/is-the-saint-from-book-of-exalted-deeds-broken

Comment: Not to mention that there are a fair number of ways to acquire temporary to permanent interference with *mind-affecting* effects. Psionics have some fairly easy options.

Comment: @nijineko: I am not well-versed in Psionics, so please feel free to add an answer of your own; or just point me to the simple options and I'll edit them in.