# Saint template and Holy Touch (Su) damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, character-templates

The supernatural ability *Holy Touch* from the [Saint](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/templates/saint.shtml) template reads:

> A saint's entire being is suffused with holy power, which likewise flows into any weapon the saint wields. A saint's melee attacks with any weapon (or unarmed) deal an additional 1d6 points of holy damage against evil creatures, and 1d8 points against evil undead and evil outsiders. Any evil creature that strikes a saint with a natural weapon takes holy damage as if hit by the saint's attack.

Is the damage dealt to an evil creature that strikes the saint with a natural weapon equal to all the holy damage the saint would inflict with an attack (for instance, if they also had the "Holy Ki Strike" feat) or only the +1d6/1d8 mentioned in the ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The evil creature should probably only take the bonus holy damage specifically provided by *Holy Touch*.

A very cheesy RAW reading of the rule could conclude that if the Saint has another source of bonus holy damage which could apply to their attacks, this damage is also done to the attacking creature. However, in the context of the ability, it seems very likely that the rule as intended is that they would only be taking the bonus damage specifically provided by the *Holy Touch* ability.

The BoED Saint template is [pretty damn overpowered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119558/28402) as it is so doesn't really need extra boosts from cheesy readings of the ability (though I guess by the same token, at that point it doesn't make too much of a difference to give it another boost, either).

Comment: What else even deals holy damage? I mean, not even the weapon special ability [*holy*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#holy) deals holy damage, Batman!

Comment: @HeyICanChan as suggested in the question, the [Holy Ki Strike](http://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/feat/Holy_Ki_Strike) feat deals explicitly holy damage. So there's at least one thing... whether there are more than that, I don't have the necessary patience to find out.

Comment: Holy Strike ACF for monk also gives bonus holy damage.

Comment: @Carcer  Is the cheesy RAW reading the only RAW reading?

Comment: @Cellheim no, I think it would still be consistent with the RAW to read it as implicitly referring only to the bonus damage from the ability and not other sources, but I couldn't categorically state that everyone would agree with me on that.